# Bash Awk division gets different results

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to calculate some values using awk.But I get different results when dividing with 100 and using linux command getconf CLK_TCK.

In my case the command always returns 100:

```
[centos@op5test1 ~]$ getconf CLK_TCK
100
```

Now I'm trying to calculate some values using the above command output value.

```
[centos@op5test1 ~]$ echo 26178 4861 | awk '{print ($1+$2)/$(getconf CLK_TCK)}'
1.18569
```

and now giving  the value 100

```
[centos@op5test1 ~]$ echo 26178 4861 | awk '{print ($1+$2)/100}'
310.39
```

Why do I get differnt values ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right way to pass output of your `getconf` command from command line:

```
echo 26178 4861 | awk -v val=$(getconf CLK_TCK) '{print ($1+$2)/val}'
310.39
```

`$(getconf CLK_TCK)` when used directly inside `awk` command is evaluated to `$0` which is `26178 4861` and you're then effectively doing:

```
print ($1+$2)/$0
```

which is performing this arithmetic:

```
(26178 + 4861)/26178 => 1.18569
```

Comment: Yup it resolved my problem.One more doubt if try to store the output valueof this (getconf CLK_TCK) in some variable and later try to use it in awk '{print ($1+$2)/$val}' is still going the store $0 in the $val in awk ?

Comment: you can use this in shell: `val=$(getconf CLK_TCK); echo 26178 4861 | awk -v val="$val" '{print ($1+$2)/val}'`